# Can I use DotNetOpenAuth with Hammock?

Tags: rest, oauth, dotnetopenauth, hammock

The consumer application I'm writing needs to use the [REST API from LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/rest). Currently I have the basic OAuth flow code working using [Hammock](https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock).

But I'm not yet storing the OAuth access tokens. I have looked at DotNetOpenAuth and concluded that using it would make the flow more readable.

What I don't yet understand is how DotNetOpenAuth and Hammock would be used together in a consumer application, if at all.

I **think** I may want to use the deserialization strategy of Hammock when I start using the actual Groups API next. I am not sure if it makes sense to use DotNetOpenAuth **for anything else** then the OAuth flow. (Perhaps only to check if the tokes are still valid if the user returns to the application?)

Does anyone have experience using both (in one application), prefer one over the other, or know of situations where you may need both to accomplish OAuth/REST related tasks?

---

PS. I am aware of the [LinkedIn Developer Toolkit](http://linkedintoolkit.codeplex.com). I have decided not to use that since but it doesn't support the [LinkedIn Groups API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/groups-api) and it hasn't been updated in a year.